# How do I select unique values as graphs series?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do I select unique values as series in graph?

For example, I have these values:

```
100 432
200 93
100 268
200 41
100 286
200 43
300 53
300 45
100 315
200 42
300 46
100 308
200 62
100 308
200 41
300 65
300 67
```

I must make a graph that would make a series of each unique value. For example, there would be a line called 100 with values "432, 268, 286...", line called 200 with graph values of "93, 41, 42..." and so on.

**How do I make such graph?**

Comment: Can you tell us what you've already tried? SuperUser is a place where we try to help those who themselves have tried to resolve something, but get stuck or run into a problem. You improve your chances of getting a response if you provide details of what you've already tried. This does two things; 1) lets us know you are willing to put in an effort and not expect someone else to just do it for you, and 2) helps us to not suggest what you've already tried.

Comment: Um, yes. I have tried filters, but that just leaves me with buch of copy pastes, and I have around 20k entries there, so that is not an option. I have tried poking around with "Select Data" form and tried few other types of graphs (mostly line and scatter types). I have tried googling alot, including functions that might help, but I was unsuccessful.